# Search selected word with shortcut in Wayland

Tags: wayland, clipboard, internet, xclip

I see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1189467/how-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard-when-using-wayland) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972287/selection-in-wayland) that `wl-clipboard` is supposed to be the `xclip` alternative for Wayland.

But I don't seem to be able to fit it with what I do with `xclip` in X11, especially *searching selected word with a shortcut*: for example, to search Google, I have the shortcut Alt-G associated with the command `sh -c 'xdg-open "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'`. Thus, after selecting a word and pressing Alt-G, the word is searched in Google. That works with any search engine.

But what's the equivalent of `xclip -o` in Wayland, and can it be used in the same way?